# HttpWebRequest Cookie Issue - (500) Internal Server Error

Tags: c#, cookies

I've recently run into an issue which I believe is related with the CookieContainer.
It is a basic HttpWebRequest to a url that was previously working fine (2 days ago) but is now having issues.
Below is the code I am using.

```
string url = "http://www.footywire.com/afl/footy/ft_match_statistics?mid=5827";

var cookieJar = new CookieContainer(); 
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url); 
request.CookieContainer = cookieJar;

request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
request.Method = "GET";
request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:29.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/29.0";
request.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";

WebHeaderCollection myWebHeaderCollection = request.Headers;
myWebHeaderCollection.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
myWebHeaderCollection.Add("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
int cookieCount = cookieJar.Count;
response.Close();
```

I am getting a (500) Internal Server Error during the GetResponse() call.
The URL works fine in the browser, but fails if I use an incognito/private window which makes me think it has to be cookie related.

I've monitored the request/responses using fiddler and can see the request is not handling cookies at all.

Here is a working request through the browser with cookies enabled.

```
GET http://www.footywire.com/afl/footy/ft_match_statistics?mid=5827 HTTP/1.1
Host: www.footywire.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:29.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/29.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Cookie: __utma=123692316.616048912.1368166198.1400452319.1400457786.25; __gads=ID=c95b71c78d8a7516:T=1368166203:S=ALNI_MbHrLnKztzLrfUEkZNoQfcimetGNw; _em_vt=3938ffa289939f5bd80fd60798185181c3303dddd6-9262208553794a3e; __utmz=123692316.1395356585.4.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); __utmc=123692316; JSESSIONID=62B598BD99DC2D228C4FC1E1549ED6FB; __utmb=123692316.1.10.1400457786; _em_v=5cc514d9ac92155cd445ac583ffd53794a3e7088d0-4657961653794a3e
Connection: keep-alive
```

This is the request the code is sending. The cookie is clearly missing.

```
GET http://www.footywire.com/afl/footy/ft_match_statistics?mid=5827 HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:29.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/29.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Host: www.footywire.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

I'm at a bit of a loss as to why its not working now, but it was 2 days ago. I'm also not sure of what to do next.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Your sample does not show adding cookies to the `cookieJar` - so code behaves as expected (unless you are not showing some important part).

Comment: I was under the impression that the CookieContainer, once attached to the request, handled it for me. As it turns out I got it working by commenting out the AllowAutoRedirect and declaring cookieJar as type CookieContainer. No idea why that worked though.